# Call a js function from a controller in rails after fb_close while fb sharing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4

In one of my app Im using an fbshare option. I implemented it like

```
<li class="facebook">
            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<%= FACEBOOK_APP_KEY %>&amp;display=popup&amp;description=<%= $fb_share_text %>&amp;name=<%= $fb_share_name %>&amp;picture=<%= request.base_url %>redirect_uri=<%= FB_CALL_BACK_URL %>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');"></a>
</li>
```

and this returns a "fb_close" url with which i have routed it to a controller method named fb_close inside my home_controller.
My app is in another window and this fb_share window opens up as a separate window. 
I also have a fb_close.html.erb view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("b");
    self.close();
</script>
```

which closes as soon as the fb share happens.

Thing is this console is printed on the window that got opened. Since its is not an ajax call request i dont have any success function which will get called as soon as this fb share happens.
I want to update a html inside a div as soon as the fb_window closes. Is there any way i can do this. Al i want is to get a js function to get called as soon the fb_close window got closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use session variables and ajax request OR close ur parent div OR open it in same window

```
   <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<%= FACEBOOK_APP_KEY %>&amp;display=popup&amp;description=<%= $fb_share_text %>&amp;name=<%= $fb_share_name %>&amp;picture=<%= request.base_url %>redirect_uri=<%= FB_CALL_BACK_URL %>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325','_self")">
```

It will open in same window.